# get the actual values from google visualization categorywrapper control

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, get, google-visualization

I have a sample google visualization controlwrapper here in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/0m7n9hLt/17/). How can I get the actual selected value of the control? 
ie, I drawn the control using column 1 and when I selected something, I want to get the values which are in column 1 instead of its formatted value like if I select CPU, the alert should be 1.
I tried with following code and it returns only the formatted value.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
         if (control.getState().selectedValues.length > 0) {
             alert(control.getState().selectedValues);
         }    
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find selected row values as demonstrated below:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {

     var selectedVals = control.getState().selectedValues;
     var dt = control.getDataTable();
     var selectedIds = getFilteredValues(dt,selectedVals);        
     alert(selectedIds);
});
```

where

```
function getFilteredValues(dataTable,values){
    var result = []; 
    for(i = 0; i< dataTable.getNumberOfRows();i++){
        var curVal = dataTable.getValue(i,0); 
        if(values.indexOf(curVal) > -1){
            var curId = dataTable.getValue(i,1);
            result.push(curId);
        }        
     }
     return result;
}
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/8xnad1ea/)